# How to write code for cancel button to undo/rollback add and update a row in progress 4gl

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have written a simple code to search some data's from the database and display it in the browser (br1) , it contains the following layout [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dZ27.png)

```
DO:
Enable 
oadd oupdate odelete ocancel with frame default-frame. 

Find First Customer where Customer.Cust-Num =input oCustNum  exclusive-lock  NO-ERROR .

if available customer

THEN  DO:

 message "1" view-as alert-box.

    update
    Customer.Name         = input oName
    Customer.Balance      = input oBalance
    Customer.Discount     = input oDiscount
    Customer.Credit-Limit = input oCredit-Limit
    Customer.Phone        = input oPhone
    Customer.Contact      = input oContact  .

        br1:refresh(). 
      end.

if not available customer 

THEN  DO: 

  message "2" view-as alert-box.
    Create Customer. 

     assign 
    Customer.Cust-Num     = input oCustNum
    Customer.Name         = input oName 
    Customer.Balance      = input oBalance 
    Customer.Discount     = input oDiscount 
    Customer.Credit-Limit = input oCredit-Limit
    Customer.Phone        = input oPhone 
    Customer.Contact      = input oContact .  

        end.     
END.
```

i have written the code of save update and add in save button.

now when the cancel button is pressed i need to undo / rollback the data's to the original value before add/update is done.

could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to rethink your design!

"Undo" implies that a transaction is open and that specific transaction is rolled back. You can do this for instance by encapsulating your entire GUI in a transaction but that is bad practice. It will give long transactions, locking issues, bi-file growth and potential crashes if somebody leaves their session open. Not a good idea - you want to make your transactions small!

You need to look into a more service based approach. For instance:

- When the interface loads you load the records your interested into a temp-table.
- When you click "add," "update", "delete" etc you make changes to these records. "Add" creates a new record in the temp-table, "update" makes changes to a record and delete deletes (or marks for delete) records in the temp-table.
- When clicking "save" you first check that no records are changed in the database, if not you save the changes from the temp-tables into the database. If they are changed you might want to alert the user.
- When clicking "cancel" you just exit and disregard the changes.

You can get support for parts of this way of by working utilizing datasets. Read up on those!

https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvpds/preface.html#

Answer (score 0):

1. /******************************************************************************* code for deleting of current input records if user press the cancel
   button. if data allready exists in the dtabase then display else
   assign the values in  the database.

   *******************************************************************************/ {mfdtitle.i} /********************VARIABLES DEFINITION
   *************************************/

   DEF VAR part LIKE pt_part NO-UNDO. DEF VAR m_desc1 LIKE pt_desc1
   NO-UNDO. DEF VAR m_desc2 LIKE pt_desc2 NO-UNDO. DEF VAR m_can AS
   LOGICAL NO-UNDO.

   /******************************************************************************/

   /*************************** FRAME
   ********************************************/

   FORM  part COLON 30 m_desc1 COLON 30 m_desc2 COLON 30 m_can COLON 30
   WITH FRAME a WIDTH 100 SIDE-LABELS. SETFRAMELABELS(FRAME a:handle).

   /******************************************************************************/ mainloop: UPDATE     part WITH FRAME a.

   FOR EACH pt_mstr WHERE pt_domain = global_domain AND pt_part = part
   NO-LOCK:    ASSIGN 
         m_desc1 = pt_desc1 
         m_desc2 = pt_desc2.
         DISPLAY m_desc1 m_desc2 WITH FRAME a. END.

   IF NOT AVAILABLE (pt_mstr) THEN  do:    UPDATE 
         m_desc1
         m_desc2
         m_can COLUMN-LABEL "CANCEL"    WITH FRAME a.

   CREATE pt_mstr.
         ASSIGN 
            pt_part = part
            pt_desc1 = m_desc1
            pt_desc2 = m_desc2. end.

   IF m_can = YES THEN  do:    UNDO mainloop ,RETRY mainloop. end.
   /*********************************************************************************/

   1. List item

Comment: Instead of m_can u can use your cancel button to undo whatever u want by using labels in your programme this was just an example